# TSQL Pivot aggregation

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot, aggregate

I have a rather complicated PIVOT query that perhaps ought to be broken up into parts. My problem is that I end up with duplicate rows that I need to get rid of.

```
        SELECT 
        PostName,
        ActivityID,
        ProjectName,
        ProjectID,
        ObjectiveID,
        ObjectiveName,
        LastName,
        FirstName,
        VolID,
        Orgs,
        Coms,
        ISNULL([Males 0-9], 0) [Males 0-9], 
        ISNULL([Males 10-17], 0) [Males 10-17], 
        ISNULL([Males 18-24], 0) [Males 18-24], 
        ISNULL([Males 25+], 0) [Males 25+], 
        ISNULL([Females 0-9], 0) [Females 0-9], 
        ISNULL([Females 10-17], 0) [Females 10-17], 
        ISNULL([Females 18-24], 0) [Females 18-24], 
        ISNULL([Females 25+], 0) [Females 25+]
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            a.PostName,
            a.ActivityID,
            pr.PostID,
            pr.ProjectName,
            pr.ProjectID,
            o.ObjectiveID,
            o.ObjectiveName,
            a.LastName,
            a.FirstName,
            a.VolID,
            ISNULL(COUNT(DISTINCT ac1.ActivityCollaboratorID), 0) AS Orgs,
            ISNULL(COUNT(DISTINCT ac2.ActivityCollaboratorID), 0) AS Coms,
            p.AddInd,
            b.Name
        FROM
            [PCVRT].[dbo].ActivityObjectives ao
                LEFT JOIN [PCVRT].[dbo].[ReportCSPPView] a
                    ON ao.ActivityID = a.ActivityID
                LEFT JOIN [PCVRT].[dbo].[ActivityParticipants] p
                    ON a.ActivityID = p.ActivityID
                        AND a.GroupName IS NOT NULL
                        AND a.MMED <> 1
                FULL OUTER JOIN [PCVRT].[dbo].Buckets b
                    ON 
                        b.BucketID = p.BucketID
                        AND b.BucketSetID = 
                        (
                            SELECT BucketSetID FROM [PCVRT].[dbo].BucketSets
                            WHERE Name = 'Standard'
                        )
                LEFT JOIN PCVRT.dbo.Objectives o
                    ON o.ObjectiveID = ao.ObjectiveID
                LEFT JOIN PCVRT.dbo.ActivityCollaborators ac1
                    ON a.ActivityID = ac1.ActivityID
                        AND ac1.CollaboratorTypeID = 1
                LEFT JOIN PCVRT.dbo.ActivityCollaborators ac2
                    ON a.ActivityID = ac2.ActivityID
                        AND ac2.CollaboratorTypeID = 2
                LEFT JOIN PCVRT.dbo.Projects pr
                    ON pr.ProjectID = a.ProjectId
        GROUP BY
            a.ActivityID,
            a.PostName,
            pr.PostID,
            pr.ProjectName,
            pr.ProjectID,
            o.ObjectiveID,
            o.ObjectiveName,
            a.LastName,
            a.FirstName,
            a.VolID,
            p.AddInd,
            b.Name

    ) AS source
    PIVOT
    (
        MAX(AddInd)
        FOR Name IN([Males 0-9], [Males 10-17], [Males 18-24], [Males 25+], [Females 0-9], [Females 10-17], [Females 18-24], [Females 25+])
    ) AS pvt
    WHERE ProjectName IS NOT NULL
        AND ObjectiveName IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY 
        ProjectID,
        ObjectiveID,
        ProjectName,
        ObjectiveName,
        LastName,
        FirstName
```

So, the result of this is like so:

```
+----------+--------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+-----------+-----------+------+------+----------+------------+------------+----------+------------+--------------+--------------+------------+
| PostName |              ActivityID              |                          ProjectName                          |              ProjectID               |             ObjectiveID              |                           ObjectiveName                            | LastName | FirstName |   VolID   | Orgs | Coms | Males0-9 | Males10-17 | Males18-24 | Males25+ | Females0-9 | Females10-17 | Females18-24 | Females25+ |
+----------+--------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+-----------+-----------+------+------+----------+------------+------------+----------+------------+--------------+--------------+------------+
| Zomba    | 1432BB61-6DC7-4EB9-B7F1-08D3BD1500ED | Youth in Development Thematic                                 | 663E5793-D40D-4543-AA63-287AF32567E6 | 1FD82DEC-A8C3-4679-9CA2-66E8977B6A30 | Community Engagement in English                                    | Amadou   | Daniel    | 100582935 |    1 |    1 |       15 |         22 |         12 |        0 |         32 |           22 |           12 |          0 |
| Zomba    | 1432BB61-6DC7-4EB9-B7F1-08D3BD1500ED | Youth in Development Thematic                                 | 663E5793-D40D-4543-AA63-287AF32567E6 | 1E4EDF72-A13A-4BCB-9C78-6A879F512A44 | Community Engagement in Literacy                                   | Amadou   | Daniel    | 100582935 |    1 |    1 |       15 |         22 |         12 |        0 |         32 |           22 |           12 |          0 |
| Zomba    | 1432BB61-6DC7-4EB9-B7F1-08D3BD1500ED | Youth in Development Thematic                                 | 663E5793-D40D-4543-AA63-287AF32567E6 | ACCAF29C-C2C8-488E-9406-6BE5FF6D1961 | Promoting Gender Equitable Practices                               | Amadou   | Daniel    | 100582935 |    1 |    1 |       15 |         22 |         12 |        0 |         32 |           22 |           12 |          0 |
| Zomba    | 1432BB61-6DC7-4EB9-B7F1-08D3BD1500ED | Youth in Development Thematic                                 | 663E5793-D40D-4543-AA63-287AF32567E6 | 819966D1-1D0E-4889-AE2F-72E0CDACF850 | Student-friendly Schools                                           | Amadou   | Daniel    | 100582935 |    1 |    1 |       15 |         22 |         12 |        0 |         32 |           22 |           12 |          0 |
| Zomba    | 1CC95367-D9EE-46ED-981E-74D3E944BBE8 | Project Test - Youth in Development Thematic                  | 543E1BF9-E17B-47AF-AE06-4C14EE494BA6 | E36000FC-BAE1-492B-823E-6F3441083727 | Increasing life skills and health education for children and youth | Allen    | Touoze    | 100343614 |    1 |    1 |        0 |         22 |         15 |       12 |          0 |           26 |           13 |          8 |
| Zomba    | 3913846E-3973-4404-B3CA-D3ECFE357C00 | Project Test - Youth in Development Thematic                  | 543E1BF9-E17B-47AF-AE06-4C14EE494BA6 | E36000FC-BAE1-492B-823E-6F3441083727 | Increasing life skills and health education for children and youth | Allen    | Touoze    | 100343614 |    1 |    2 |        0 |          2 |          0 |        0 |          0 |           12 |            2 |          0 |
| Zomba    | 1432BB61-6DC7-4EB9-B7F1-08D3BD1500ED | Secondary / Community Activities - Education Sector Framework | 06C877D7-317B-432C-B038-A548AC7BB59F | 1FD82DEC-A8C3-4679-9CA2-66E8977B6A30 | Community Engagement in English                                    | Amadou   | Daniel    | 100582935 |    1 |    1 |       15 |         22 |         12 |        0 |         32 |           22 |           12 |          0 |
| Zomba    | 1432BB61-6DC7-4EB9-B7F1-08D3BD1500ED | Secondary / Community Activities - Education Sector Framework | 06C877D7-317B-432C-B038-A548AC7BB59F | 1E4EDF72-A13A-4BCB-9C78-6A879F512A44 | Community Engagement in Literacy                                   | Amadou   | Daniel    | 100582935 |    1 |    1 |       15 |         22 |         12 |        0 |         32 |           22 |           12 |          0 |
| Zomba    | 1432BB61-6DC7-4EB9-B7F1-08D3BD1500ED | Secondary / Community Activities - Education Sector Framework | 06C877D7-317B-432C-B038-A548AC7BB59F | ACCAF29C-C2C8-488E-9406-6BE5FF6D1961 | Promoting Gender Equitable Practices                               | Amadou   | Daniel    | 100582935 |    1 |    1 |       15 |         22 |         12 |        0 |         32 |           22 |           12 |          0 |
| Zomba    | 1432BB61-6DC7-4EB9-B7F1-08D3BD1500ED | Secondary / Community Activities - Education Sector Framework | 06C877D7-317B-432C-B038-A548AC7BB59F | 819966D1-1D0E-4889-AE2F-72E0CDACF850 | Student-friendly Schools                                           | Amadou   | Daniel    | 100582935 |    1 |    1 |       15 |         22 |         12 |        0 |         32 |           22 |           12 |          0 |
+----------+--------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+-----------+-----------+------+------+----------+------------+------------+----------+------------+--------------+--------------+------------+
```

So, what I need is to only get one row per Project->Objective pairing, rolling up the Activities.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

You did not provide what you want as the final result, but based on your current result I am make a few guesses as to what the problem is.

When you are applying the PIVOT function, you should only include columns that you actually need to display in your final result because all columns in the select list that are not a part of the aggregate function or the PIVOT columns will be grouped.

Your current data has multiple values for the `ObjectiveId` column so when you include that column, you will have multiple rows displayed in your final result.

I am guessing that you should use something similar to the following:

```
SELECT 
    PostName,
    ActivityID,
    ProjectName,
    ProjectID,
    ObjectiveName,
    LastName,
    FirstName,
    VolID,
    Orgs,
    Coms,
    ISNULL([Males 0-9], 0) [Males 0-9], 
    ISNULL([Males 10-17], 0) [Males 10-17], 
    ISNULL([Males 18-24], 0) [Males 18-24], 
    ISNULL([Males 25+], 0) [Males 25+], 
    ISNULL([Females 0-9], 0) [Females 0-9], 
    ISNULL([Females 10-17], 0) [Females 10-17], 
    ISNULL([Females 18-24], 0) [Females 18-24], 
    ISNULL([Females 25+], 0) [Females 25+]
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        a.PostName,
        a.ActivityID,
        pr.PostID,
        pr.ProjectName,
        pr.ProjectID,
        o.ObjectiveName,
        a.LastName,
        a.FirstName,
        a.VolID,
        ISNULL(COUNT(DISTINCT ac1.ActivityCollaboratorID), 0) AS Orgs,
        ISNULL(COUNT(DISTINCT ac2.ActivityCollaboratorID), 0) AS Coms,
        p.AddInd,
        b.Name
    FROM [PCVRT].[dbo].ActivityObjectives ao
    LEFT JOIN [PCVRT].[dbo].[ReportCSPPView] a
        ON ao.ActivityID = a.ActivityID
    LEFT JOIN [PCVRT].[dbo].[ActivityParticipants] p
        ON a.ActivityID = p.ActivityID
            AND a.GroupName IS NOT NULL
            AND a.MMED <> 1
    FULL OUTER JOIN [PCVRT].[dbo].Buckets b
        ON 
            b.BucketID = p.BucketID
            AND b.BucketSetID = 
            (
                SELECT BucketSetID FROM [PCVRT].[dbo].BucketSets
                WHERE Name = 'Standard'
            )
    LEFT JOIN PCVRT.dbo.Objectives o
        ON o.ObjectiveID = ao.ObjectiveID
    LEFT JOIN PCVRT.dbo.ActivityCollaborators ac1
        ON a.ActivityID = ac1.ActivityID
            AND ac1.CollaboratorTypeID = 1
    LEFT JOIN PCVRT.dbo.ActivityCollaborators ac2
        ON a.ActivityID = ac2.ActivityID
            AND ac2.CollaboratorTypeID = 2
    LEFT JOIN PCVRT.dbo.Projects pr
        ON pr.ProjectID = a.ProjectId
    GROUP BY
        a.ActivityID,
        a.PostName,
        pr.PostID,
        pr.ProjectName,
        pr.ProjectID,
        o.ObjectiveName,
        a.LastName,
        a.FirstName,
        a.VolID,
        p.AddInd,
        b.Name

) AS source
PIVOT
(
    MAX(AddInd)
    FOR Name IN([Males 0-9], [Males 10-17], [Males 18-24], 
                [Males 25+], [Females 0-9], [Females 10-17], 
                [Females 18-24], [Females 25+])
) AS pvt
WHERE ProjectName IS NOT NULL
    AND ObjectiveName IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY ProjectID, ProjectName, ObjectiveName, LastName,  FirstName
```